# Mongodb aggregation pipeline, combine result from two facet pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm having a claim type:

```
type TClaim: {
  insuredId: number,
  treatmentInfo: { amount: number }[]
 }
```

and a list of claims:

```
[
 {
  insuredId: 1,
  treatmentInfo: [{amount: 1}, {amount: 2}]
 },
 {
  insuredId: 1,
  treatmentInfo: [{amount: 3}, {amount: 4}]
 },
 {
  insuredId: 2,
  treatmentInfo: [{amount: 1}, {amount: 2}]
 }
]
```

I want to get the result like:

```
[{insuredId: 1, numberOfClaims: 2, amount: 10},{insuredId: 2, numberOfClaims: 1, amount: 3}]
```

I'm using the $facet operator in mongodb aggregation, one for counting numberOfClaims and one for calculating the amount of each insurer. But I can't combine it to get the result that I want.

```
$facet: {
 totalClaims: [ { $group: { _id: '$insuredId', totalClaims: {  $count: {} } } } ],
 amount: [ { $unwind: { path: '$treatmentInfo'}}, 
       { $group: 
          {  _id: '$insuredId', 
             amount: {  $sum: '$treatmentInfo.amount',
          },
        },
      },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want to use $facet? - I am just curious

You just need to add a new fields that sums up all the amount in the array first and then do a group stage by insuredId. The query is pretty much self-explanatory.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "totalAmount": {
        "$sum": "$treatmentInfo.amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$insuredId",
      "numberOfClaims": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "amount": {
        "$sum": "$totalAmount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "amount": 10,
    "numberOfClaims": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "amount": 3,
    "numberOfClaims": 1
  }
]
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i3o1aOKLSpZ)

Comment: Slightly simpler version https://mongoplayground.net/p/u2HH5rHrkMS

Comment: That works too, nice 

Comment: Oh it's right, I didn't think of it. Thank you so much.